# Can't call method out of a timer. Why?

Tags: java, android, timer

I have another problem i can't solve by myselve.

My situation:
I have four FrameLayouts in LinearLayouts.

[image]

I color them, set Layout hight and width at wrap content and just change the minwidth to use them as a status or progress bar.

To adjust the bars i have a method:

```
public void update_bars(){

    FrameLayout bar_eat = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar_eat);
    FrameLayout bar_drink = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar_drink);
    FrameLayout bar_wash = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar_wash);
    FrameLayout bar_care = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar_care);

    bar_eat.setMinimumWidth((int)(((float)screen_part/1000)*eat));
    bar_drink.setMinimumWidth((int)(((float)screen_part/1000)*drink));
    bar_wash.setMinimumWidth((int)(((float)screen_part/1000)*wash));
    bar_care.setMinimumWidth((int)(((float)screen_part/1000)*care));
}
```

This method works fine from everywhere in my activity.
But i also want to call this update_bars() method every second so i made a timer for it.

```
private void update(){

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            update_bars()

        }   

    },0,(1000* getResources().getInteger(R.integer.remove_speed_inSecond)));
```

But at this point it crashes....

The debugger says this:

> Thread [<12> Timer-0] (ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException)
>       Timer$TimerImpl.run() Zeile: 290

So where it the problem? And what can i do?
I woud be very happy if someone have an idear because i'm going crazy^^

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized"; this is a "please debug my code for me" question.

Comment: Right, it was an question linke this. But what shoud i do else if i can't figurout the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer creates new thread. You can't update UI from non UI thread. Use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much :) runOnUiThread worked for me. 
Quit simple^^ :)